# How to segment the actual human body shape from an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

As per my requirement, from single image of a dressed human (say wearing pant and shirt) with clear and plain background, Which algorithm can draw outline of an human body shape for only the pose given in the image. I am using opencv c++ library. All I can hear for now, is grabcut and contours but they only draw outline around the outfit but I need outline around inside body shape after eliminating outfit. Any algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: IF you have the pause already, there is a function in opencv that finds the "best match contour" and return its boundaries/coordinates. I used it once for shape detection where I had the shapes already and it worked awesome

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples in internet,generally speaking we often use the HOG descriptor to detect pedestrian you can search some information about

> HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector
>
> HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector()

here is a simple sample code about you request:
[enter link description here](http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2011/12/04/people-detection-sample-from-opencv/)

Comment: Thanks. But can HOG descriptors extract body shape from a dressed photo? I thought it can just identify humans and draw rectangle to mark them in a frame.